# .NET Framework plugin system - error on calling Assembly.GetExportedTypes()

Tags: .net, assembly.load

We have a third party .NET Framework application that enables users to load their own plugins.
Plugins are just standard .NET dlls that the application loads with Assembly.Load().

I'm trying to create a sort of subplugins system, where my plugin loads it's own subplugins.

To test it I created a simple example:

In my plugin dll I declare interface ISubPlugin()

```cs
public interface ISubPlugin
{
    void Init();
}
```

and a bit of code to load subplugins

```cs
var asm = Assembly.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@"C:\...\CallbackPluginTest.dll"));
foreach (var t in asm.GetExportedTypes())
{
    foreach (var i in t.GetInterfaces())
    {
        if (i == typeof(ISubPlugin))
        {
            var o = (ISubPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            o.InitPlugin();
        }
    }
}
```

Assembly.Load() works just fine, it loads the subplugin dll, but when asm.GetExportedTypes() is called I get an error saying that it can't find the assembly XXX, where XXX is the assembly that defines ISubPlugin().
So basically .NET can't load assembly that is already loaded, and is in fact the assembly that calls asm.GetEportedTypes().
Weirder still, if I put the XXX assembly dll into the application folder then asm.GetExportedTypes() works, but the condition i == typeof(ISubPlugin) is not met, event though VS debugger shows that it returns true.

Tried searching for some kind of solution or at least an explanation for this behavior on the web but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Are they maybe linking different framework versions? Side note: you can simplify with `if (t.IsAssignableTo(typeof(ISubPlugin))) { var o = ...` instead of the inner `foreach`

Comment: Main application, plugin and subplugin dlls all target the same .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Do they (the actual DLL and the reference to the DLL from the plugin) have different Public Key or version numbers maybe? Please post the full error message (you can obfuscate the name, leave everything else).

Comment: Both plugin DLL and subplugin DLL are projects in the same solution. On subplugin project I just added reference to plugin project, so it should reference the proper version.

The error message (in Polish) is:
Nie można załadować pliku lub zestawu 'XXX, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=15b4fed6b5ae1d9a' lub jednej z jego zależności. Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku.

Comment: OK did you add it as a project reference, or as a reference to a DLL? If they are in the same solution you should add them as project references. Also do they reference each other (circular references)?

Comment: I added it as a project reference and they do not reference each other. Only subplugin assembly references the plugin assembly.